# Direct flattening of records from dataframe in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, flatten

I have a question whether we have any direct or a simple approach to flatten the data than what I am describing as below to implement in PySpark/Hive.

I have a dataset in one table which looks like below:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([("123","000"),("456","123"),("789","456"),("111","000"),("999","888")])
df = rdd.toDF(["active_acct","inactive_acct"])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_main_active_accts")
temp_main_active_accts_pd=temp_main_active_accts.toPandas()

df.show()
```

```
| active_acct | inactive_acct |

| 123         |  000  |
| 456         |  123  |
| 789         |  456  |
| 111         |  000  |
| 999         |  888  |
```

I am expecting the final output to be like:

```
| Current_active | all_old_active |

| 789 | 456,123,000 |
| 111 | 000 |
| 999 | 888 |
```

Which means 789 is the current active record and the records 456,123,000 one or the other time were active and this is the reason you can see recursive link in the main table.

I had to get to the latest record i.e. 789 so that I can find the link to the previous credit cards. I have query which gets to the latest account used and returns the records like :

```
active_accts=spark.sql("select active_acct,inactive_acct from temp_main_active_accts where active_acct not in 
(select t1.active_acct from temp_main_active_accts t1 join temp_main_active_accts t2 on t1.active_acct=t2.inactive_acct)")

active_accts.show()
```

```
| active_acct | inactive_acct |
| 789         | 456 |
| 111         | 000 |
| 999         | 888 |
```

Below is the logic to flatten the records with a UDF but, the problem is this is taking a lot of time to run. I was looking whether we have any simple solution to do this so that I can avoid the UDF implementation here or any other way which is much simple. May it be sql or pyspark based.

```
global old_acc_list

def first_itr(active_acc):
 qry="""active_account == '{0}'""".format(active_acc)
 active_acc_pd=(temp_main_active_accts_pd.query(qry))
 active_acc_pd=active_acc_pd.drop_duplicates()
 active_acc_pd=active_acc_pd.reset_index(drop=True)
 active_acc_cnt=active_acc_pd.size
 if active_acc_cnt>0:
  inactive_acc=active_acc_pd['old_active'].astype(str)[0]
  global old_acc_list
  old_acc_list+=","+str(inactive_acc)
  first_itr(inactive_acc)
 else:
  old_acc_list=old_acc_list.lstrip(",")
  return old_acc_list

extract_old_acc_udf=udf(lambda row: first_itr(row),StringType())
df_final=active_accts.withColumn("all_old_accs",extract_old_acc_udf(col['old_active_acc']))
```

Comment: what do `old_active_acc` and `old_active` columns have?

Comment: also, does the actual data have a timestamp against the records that helps identify the order?

Comment: @samkart -- Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, there is no timestamp column which can identify. But even if we have the timestamp column we still have to query the whole table for getting the old credit cards.